# How to delete multiple selected item from android listview and remove it from the adapter as well?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, listviewitem

So, I have a listview and an adapter that populates the data into the listview.

Each row in the list item has a checkbox. And there is a button in the fragment that allows deleting the checked items from the database using their id.

However, I want this to happen:

1. The user checks/unchecks the items he wished to delete.
2. He then clicks the delete multiple items button on the fragment.
3. The items get deleted from the database.
4. The items are no longer shown in the list view. i.e. they are removed.

I have achieved all 3 of the above steps. But I am struggling with the last one. I could remove a single item from the list view when clicked on the image button but the problem is with multiple items.

***CODE FOR ADAPTER:***

```
public class ReqFoodAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
// the arraylist that holds the data of the checked items
    private ArrayList<String> checkedList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    Bitmap image,receivedBitmap;



    public ReqFoodAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
// initializing each item in the arraylist
        for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++ ){
            checkedList.add(i,"0");
        }
    }
//method to return the arraylist to the fragment
    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedList(){
        return checkedList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;

        if(convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_req_food, null);
        TextView fid = vi.findViewById(R.id.lv_req_id);
        TextView name = vi.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        TextView qty = vi.findViewById(R.id.item_req_qty);
        TextView ngoAdd = vi.findViewById(R.id.ngo_address);
        TextView resName = vi.findViewById(R.id.ngoName);
        ImageView type = vi.findViewById(R.id.type);
        ImageView thumb_image = vi.findViewById(R.id.ngo_image);
        ImageView btn_req_confirm = vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_req_confirm);
//checkbox in each row
        CheckBox checkBox = vi.findViewById(R.id.chkThisRequest);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        HashMap<String, String> food = new HashMap<String, String>();

        food = data.get(position);
        checkBox.setTag(position + "," + food.get(FoodRequests.KEY_ID));
        fid.setText(food.get(FoodRequests.KEY_ID));
        name.setText(food.get(FoodRequests.KEY_NAME));
        qty.setText(food.get(FoodRequests.KEY_REQ_QTY) + " kg");
        ngoAdd.setText(food.get(FoodRequests.KEY_NGO_ADD));

        resName.setText(food.get(FoodRequests.KEY_NGO_NAME));
        if(food.get(FoodRequests.KEY_TYPE).equals("Veg"))
            type.setImageResource(R.drawable.veg);
        else if(food.get(FoodRequests.KEY_TYPE).equals("Non-Veg"))
            type.setImageResource(R.drawable.non_veg);


        btn_req_confirm.setTag(position + "," + food.get(FoodRequests.KEY_ID));
        btn_req_confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                String arrayTag[] = ((String) view.getTag()).split(",");
                String key = arrayTag[1];
                //Update the database using key here
                int pos = Integer.parseInt(arrayTag[0]);
                data.remove(pos);
                ReqFoodAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        });
        return vi;
    }




    // onchecked change of the checkbox, change the checkedList value to the id
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

        String arrayTag[] = ((String) compoundButton.getTag()).split(",");
        String key = arrayTag[1];
        int pos = Integer.parseInt(arrayTag[0]);
        if(b) {
            checkedList.set(pos, key);

        }else{
            checkedList.set(pos,"0");

        }
    }
    // method to remove item
    public void removeItem(int index){
        data.remove(ReqFoodAdapter.this.getItem(index));
    }

    public void updateListView(){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

*** CODE FOR FRAGMENT***:

```
public class FoodRequests extends Fragment {

    public FoodRequests() {
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food_requests, container, false);

        lvReqFood = rootview.findViewById(R.id.list_req_food);
        arrListReqFood = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadReqFood().execute();
        btnConfirmAll = rootview.findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmAll);
        // button confirm multiple reuqests
        btnConfirMultiple = rootview.findViewById(R.id.btnConfirmMultiple);

        return rootview;
    }

    private class LoadReqFood extends AsyncTask<String, String, String >{
        ProgressDialog loadingRequests;



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loadingRequests.dismiss();
            adapter = new ReqFoodAdapter(getActivity(), arrListReqFood);
            lvReqFood.setAdapter(adapter);
            btnConfirMultiple.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   // get the checked list
                    ArrayList<String> checkedList = adapter.getCheckedList();
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < checkedList.size(); i++){
                                temp.put(String.valueOf(i + 1), checkedList.get(i));
                        }

                    joAllRequests.put("requests",temp.toString());
                    }catch (JSONException j){
                        j.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // update the database using each of the id of the list
                    new UpdateRequest().execute();

                }
            });
        }
    }




    private class UpdateRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        String msg;



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ArrayList<String> checkedList = adapter.getCheckedList();
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedList.size(); i++){
                if(!checkedList.get(i).equals("0")) {
                    String arrayTag[] = checkedList.get(i).split(",");
                    int pos = Integer.parseInt(arrayTag[0]);
                    adapter.removeItem(pos);
                }
            }
            adapter.updateListView();

        }
    }
}
```

So, the data gets loaded, selected items get updated, but when I wish to remove the item from the listview, it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception. It is because, what I have figured out when one item is removed from the data, its position gets altered and when I pass another item to be removed with a given position, it throws an error.

How to go about this?

Or are there any better approaches to my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the problem of position change, just revese the direction of for-loop, so the code like this:

```
    ArrayList<String> checkedList = adapter.getCheckedList();
    for (int i = checkedList.size() - 1; i => 0; i--){
        if(!checkedList.get(i).equals("0")) {
            String arrayTag[] = checkedList.get(i).split(",");
            int pos = Integer.parseInt(arrayTag[0]);
            adapter.removeItem(pos);
        }
    }
    adapter.resetCheckedList();
    adapter.updateListView();
```

The checklist also need to reset after removed items, so constructor of the adpater can be changed like this:

```
public ReqFoodAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    resetCheckedList();
}

public void resetCheckedList(){
    checkedList.clear();
    // initializing each item in the arraylist
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++ ){
        checkedList.add(i,"0");
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem. But when I check one item and remove it from the list, the other item comes up the list with its checkbox selected by default. Can u tell why?

Comment: Inside getView(), there is no code to set CheckBox according to the value in the checkedList. Add `checkBox.setChecked(checkedList.get(position) != "0");`

Comment: In where? onCheckedChanged() method or the arraylist initialization method?

Comment: Inside getView(), after setText() for the TextViews.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. You are a life saver!!